# Transfer/cancel booking gives error message

Tags: civievent

We use the CiviCRM event-booking feature on our website. The self-service cancel/transfer option isn't enabled, so attendees who want to cancel their booking for an event will email or call us and we cancel their place manually by logging in as administrators. I haven't had to do this for a while, and it's not now working.

[![Find Participants screen for an event][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPD6B.png

I tried to do this by logging in to our Wordpress site and going to: CiviCRM > Events > Manage Events > Find Participants > More > Transfer or Cancel, as hopefully shown in the image above.

The error I get is "Sorry. This event registration can not be transferred or cancelled. Contact the event organizer if you have questions."

[image: Error message after clicking Transfer or cancel]

When logged in as an admin, should this option work, regardless of whether self-service is enabled?

Thanks very much for any suggestions.

Comment: I've just worked out another way to do this, and it worked!

Comment: On the Manage Events page, I clicked Participants and chose Registered etc. Then ticked the select box beside the person I wanted to cancel. I clicked the Actions dropdown menu and chose Cancel registration > Confirm. And that worked. When I checked in the list of Cancelled participants, the person was there.

Answer (score 3):

This is a new addition in core via https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/18067. You MUST have the below setting enabled in event -> online registration tab to transfer or cancel participants belonging to that event.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll give this a try. I hadn't realised that self service had to be activated in order for an administrator to manage transfer/cancellation of event participants.

Comment: This seems like a undesirable new limitation.  We do not want participants to be able to transfer or cancel their registration, but we do need our staff to be able to transfer or cancel a registration.

Comment: As of CiviCRM 5.38, this is [no longer true](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20150).